# Python Fruit Machine - Looping back to input

Tags: python, loops

I need to make a fruit machine in Python. The fruits/items spinning are ***Cherry, Lemon, Bell, Star and Skull.*** The Success criteria is •

**• If two symbols are rolled the user wins 50p.**

**• If two skulls are rolled user loses £1, if three skulls are rolled loses all money.**

**• If you get 3 of the same you get £1, if 3 bells rolled £5.**

**• Starts with £1, each go costs 20p.**

How do I loop it back to the question "Roll" or "Quit" and how do I make it so that is a user enters something other than roll or quit it says "Oops try again"? - Please explain any changes to the code as I just know the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your program in an infinite loop like this:

```
while True:
    start = input("Enter Roll or Quit? ")
    # [more code]
```

This way, your program will always start over. If you get an invalid input use `continue` to jump back to the beginning of the loop to get another input. If the user wants to quit use `break` to exit the loop.

Comment: Whenever I put the break after the if start == quit. Then type quit it stops but when I type roll its still breaks the code. Image - [link](https://gyazo.com/914c02f009de4e2ac5ef3632a7214792)

Comment: @Sam You want `start == "quit" or start == "Quit"`, otherwise you're testing if `"Quit"` (the string) is true which is always the case.

Comment: `reel1 == "Skull" == reel2 =="Skull" == reel3 == "Skull"` should be `reel1 == "Skull" and reel2 =="Skull" and reel3 == "Skull"` BTW. Check your other conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the help.